# How can I merge 2 dictionaries into one array?

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, merge, swift5

My JSON data look like this image below. Now I wanna merge the `value` of Shop Type and Promotion into one to use as collection view data. How can I do that?

I just filter the response data from the server like this:

```
        var dataBanDau: [SDFilterModel] = []
        var quickData: [SDFilterModel] = []

        let filters: [SDFilterModel] = data

        self.filterEntries = filters

        //let nsarray = NSArray(array: self.filterEntries! , copyItems: true)
//            self.filterEntriesStoreConstant = nsarray as! Array

        self.dataBanDau = filters

        for i in 0..<self.dataBanDau.count {
            if self.dataBanDau[i].search_key.count == 0 {
                self.quickData.append(self.dataBanDau[i])
            }
        }

        self.quickData = self.quickData.filter {
            $0.type != "range"
        }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            //Note: Reload TableView
            self.quickFilterCollection.reloadData()
            completed(true)
        }
    }
```

the class `SDFilterModel`:

```
class SDFilterModel: DSBaseModel {
    var name = String()
    var type = String()
    var is_expanded = Int()
    var search_key = String()
    var filterEntries : [SDFilterModel]?

    override func copy(with zone: NSZone? = nil) -> Any {
        // This is the reason why `init(_ model: GameModel)`
        // must be required, because `GameModel` is not `final`.
        let copy = SDFilterModel(dict: self.dictionary)

        if let arrAttribute = NSArray(array: self.value , copyItems: true) as? [AttributeValueModel] {
            copy.value = arrAttribute
        }

        return copy
    }

    override init(dict: Dictionary<String, Any>) {
        super.init(dict: dict);
        value = self.valueParse()

        name = dict.getString(forKey: "name")
        type = dict.getString(forKey: "type")
        search_key = dict.getString(forKey: "search_key")
        is_expanded = dict.getInt(forKey: "is_expanded")!
    }


    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    var value: [AttributeValueModel] = [];

    func valueParse()-> [AttributeValueModel] {
        guard let childs  = (self.dictionary["value"]) as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>]
            else { return [] }

        var output: [AttributeValueModel] = [];

        for  aDict in childs {
            let item = AttributeValueModel(dict:aDict);

//            if type == .Range  && item.option_id == "0" {
//                item.setRangeOptionID(aValue: item.option_name!)
//            }
//
            output.append(item);
        }

        return output;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Show your model struct/class

Comment: You can use `map`.

Comment: Study about map function, it can helps but probably the solution is using a flatMap.

Comment: `var filterEntries : [SDFilterModel]?` This shouldn't be `SDFilterModel`. Create a new struct type for `filterEntries`. Check my answer

Comment: @iOSDev I've updated my code.
@JBarros35 I have to read about both `map` and `flatMap`. But don't know how to apply to this situation.

Comment: @Bad_Developer Instead of `map` and `flatMap` you can use `for` loop. Check my previous comment and my answer

Comment: @Bad_Developer Just do this `let reqArray = myModel.data.map({ $0.value }).flatMap({ $0 })`. Now `reArray` is the contains  values of `value` key in a single array.

Comment: have you tired jsonDecoder for appending data to model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let be Assume you have `let myArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`

Now you wanted to square of each and every element in the array,

With for loop you do like this

```
for item in myArray {
    print(item * item) 
}
```

Now assume `item = $0`

With for **map** you jus do

```
myArray.map({ $0 * $0 })
```

Both will gave same output.

---

**map :** Use to do same operation on every element of array.

**flatmap :** It is used to flattern the array of array.

```
let myArr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6,7]]
```

and you want o/p as `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

So can get above output with `myArr.flatMap({$0})`

---

Now back to your question.

```
let reqArray = myModel.data.map({ $0.value }).flatMap({ $0 })
```

First, `map` gaves you array-of-array of key `value` but you need a single array, so for that you need to use `flatmap.`

---

You can take ref : https://medium.com/@Dougly/higher-order-functions-in-swift-sorted-map-filter-reduce-dff60b5b6adf

Answer (score 0):

Create the models like this

```
struct Option {
    let name: String
    let searchKey: String
    let id: String
}

struct Model {
    let type: String
    let name: String
    let isExpanded: Bool
    let value: [Option]
}
```

You should get the `options` array values and join all the arrays

```
let models:[Model] = //...
let collectionViewArray = models.map { $0.value }.reduce([Option](), +)
```

Using `for` loop

```
var collectionViewArray = [Option]()
for model  in models {
    collectionViewArray.append(contentsOf: model.value)
}
```

Comment: Why you using `reduce` ??

Comment: I thought, [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) saying something else.

Comment: You forgot to filter

Comment: @dahiya_boy We can use `reduce` for this also. `[1,2].reduce(0,+)` gives `3`. And `[[1],[2]].reduce([Int](),+)` gives `[1,2]`.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson What to filter? I don't understand

Comment: @dahiya_boy This is simple form of `models.map { $0.value }.reduce(into: [Option]()) { $0.append(contentsOf: $1) }`

Comment: Read the question carefully, OP only wants values for keys matching two different values.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I think the question is only about getting all `Option`s in one array

Comment: @JoakimDanielson "_I wanna merge the value of Shop Type and Promotion into one to use as collection view data_"

Comment: Exactly, and there are most likely more keys present if you look at the image.Anyway, we can let the OP be the judge of this.

Comment: @iOSDev `Reduce` is use to reduce the array into single element, you need to use `flatmap` here to flattern the array-of-array